# Why does it print five times 5 instead of 1 2 3 4 5?

Tags: c++, arrays, object

I got confused why this code prints five times 5 instead 1 2 3 4 5.
If I change the code to T t[4], then the output is four times 4.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
    static int x;
public:
    Test() { x++; }
    static int getX() {return x;}
};

int Test::x = 0;

int main()
{

    Test t[5];
    for (auto element : t)
    {
    cout << element.getX() << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: What does the debugger say?

Comment: Because there is a single variable named `Test::x`.  `Test`s constructor is called 5 times, which increments `Test::x` every time, giving a result of `5`.   Then the loop starts, and `Test::x` (which remains as `5`) is printed five times.

Answer (score 5):

`x` is static; every instance of `Test` sees the same value.

When `Test t[5]` is declared and initialized, the `Test()` constructor is called five times; each call increments the one shared value of `x`. Once that array is fully initialized, x is 5.

When you call `getX()` on each element, they all return that shared value. If you want each to have its own value, increment `x` but assign the incremented value to a non-static member variable:

```
class Test
{
    static int y;
    int x;
public:
    Test() { y++; x = y; }
    static int getX() {return x;}
};
```

Comment: I would use `Test() { x = ++y; }` or even `Test() : x(++y) {}` but the end result is the same either way

Comment: @RemyLebeau I would also do that if I were writing this myself; I am keeping the old structure as closely as possible (just with the extra assignment) since other readers (especially beginners) might benefit from having the change be as simple and plain as possible.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a variable as static:

```
static int x;
```

... that means there is only one instance of that variable in your program, regardless of how many instances of `Test` you instantiate.  That is, all of your `Test` objects are referencing that single `x`.

Probably what you want is to declare a separate (non-static) variable as well, and set it from `x`:

```
class Test
{
   static int x;
   int y;

public:
   Test() { y = ++x; }
   int getY() const {return y;}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Class variable `x` is static, initialized to zero. It is incremented five times - in each of the five constructor invocations when the array `t` is created, so by the time your loop runs it has the value of `5`.